# How do I render a comma delimited list using xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt

I am rendering a list of tickers to html via xslt and I would like for the list to be comma deliimited.  Assuming I was going to use xsl:for-each...

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Tickers/Ticker">
    <xsl:value-of select="TickerSymbol"/>,
</xsl:for-each>
```

What is the best way to get rid of the trailing comma? Is there something better than xsl:for-each?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Tickers/Ticker">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="TickerSymbol"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Don't know if you meant to encode the greater than symbol or not, but using .Net the correct syntax was:

<xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>

Answer (score 7):

In **XSLT 2.0** you could do it (*without a for-each*) using the [**string-join** function](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-xquery-operators-20021115/#func-string-join):

```
<xsl:value-of  select="string-join(/Tickers/Ticker, ',')"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently using .Net 2.0 so as far as I know xslt 2.0 is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 1.0, another alternative to using xsl:for-each would be to use xsl:apply-templates

```
<xsl:template match="/">

   <!-- Output first element without a preceding comma -->
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/Tickers/Ticker[position()=1]" />

   <!-- Output subsequent elements with a preceding comma -->
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/Tickers/Ticker[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="separator">,</xsl:with-param>
   </xsl:apply-templates>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Ticker">
   <xsl:param name="separator" />
   <xsl:value-of select="$separator" /><xsl:value-of select="TickerSymbol" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you said xsl 2.0 is not an option and it has been a long time since the question was asked, but for all those searching for a posibility to do what you wanted to achieve:

There is an easier way in xsl 2.0 or higher

```
<xsl:value-of separator=", " select="/Tickers/Ticker/TickerSymbol" />
```

This will read your /Tickers/Ticker elements and insert ', ' as separator where  needed

If there is an easier  way to do this I am looking forward for advice

Regards Kevin

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, even though it's not technically an answer to the question.